# Integral of a standard gaussian distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Please see the image. I know that the integral of P(x) tends to 1. But the quadratic equation next to P(x) seems confusing.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? please use mathjax to typeset math.

Comment: I am new to this forum. So, please click on the link to view the image

Comment: Edit your question for the image to appear in your post.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: click on the 'edit' button on this answer to understand how to format your questions using Mathjax*

You are trying to evaluate:
$$
\int p(x) (ax^2 + bx+c)dx
$$
you can break this up into:
$$
a \int p(x)x^2dx + b\int p(x)xdx+ c\int p(x)dx
$$
Then use the following facts:
$$
\int p(x) x^2dx = \mathbb{E}(x^2) = Var(x) + \mathbb{E}(x)^2
$$
and
$$
\int p(x) x dx= \mathbb{E}(x)
$$
and finally:
$$
\int p(x)dx = 1
$$